# a am getting an OpenCV Error in python... and my code is given below?? Please resolve it fast.Thnks in advance

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

plese solve this guys,
when i am running this code it is giving me an unaccepted error =
""OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0) in resize, file /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 3492""

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import dlib
import cv2
import face_recognition
import os

path = 'images'
image = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)


for cl in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')
    image.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])
    # print(classNames)



def findEncodings(image):
    encodeList = []
    for img in image:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)
        return encodeList



encodeListKnown = findEncodings(image)
print(len("Encoding Complete"))



cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
# print(cap)



while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    facesCurFrames = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    encodesCurFrames = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, 
    facesCurFrames)

    for encodeFace,faceLoc in zip(encodesCurFrames, 
    facesCurFrames):
        matches = 
    face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown,encodeFace)
        faceDis = 
    face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown,encodeFace)

    print(faceDis)
```

Comment: Somewhere you are passing one or two values that are <= 0 for width and/or height to an OpenCV function. Where is the Python exception and traceback? I would suspect `cv2.resize(img, (0,0), None, 0.25, 0.25)` being the line, with the second argument of `(0,0)` being the problem.

Comment: This error is basically showing that you have an empty image. Do check if the image is being read from the path specified.

Answer (score 1):

`(0, 0)` is not a valid `(width, height)` tuple for resizing an image. It looks like you wanted to resize the image by scaling, in which case you can pass `None` instead of the size tuple:

```
imgS = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
```

will scale the image by 0.25 in both dimensions.

Comment: @Fearless: Time to start debugging. What _exactly_ is the error? Can you show the Python traceback to locate the exact place in your code that the error starts. What is the value of `success` after `cap.read()`? Check the properties of `img` - is it empty, does it have zero sized dimensions? etc.

Comment: Also check whether `img` is None before calling `resize()`.